# How to add estimate shipping and tax in PayPal

Tags: paypal

I want to add an option to the buyers so they can add the zip code of their state in they get the total amount of money they should pay and this is a screenshot for the option that I want to add.

[image: Estimate shipping and tax]

Comment: Is [this what you are looking for](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/shipping-calculator)? If you want something _at your site_ then you'll have to build that yourself and send the related costs you pre-calculated to Paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your PayPal account.  In the top bar, click 'Tools'.  Click the link that says 'Buttons', it should be in the top left.  On the right side, click 'Create new button'. This page has a lot of options, take a look around.

To set up your shipping options for your PayPal account, again go to 'Tools', then 'Shipping Calculations' (should be along the bottom), at this page you can start to customize your Domestic and International shipping options.